# Comparing two variable strings not working

Tags: java, android-activity

```
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                String answer = mEdit.getText().toString();
                questioncount++;


                if (answer.equals(check)) {
                    currentscore++;
                    //t3.setText("CORRECT");

                }
                else {
                    currentscore--;
                    //t3.setText("WRONG");
                };


                t4.setText(answer+" "+currentscore);
                t2.setText("Question "+questioncount+" of 20");

                final double randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(arraycount+1));
                t.setText(gcse_defs[(int) randomnumber]);
                String check = gcse_terms[(int) randomnumber];
                t3.setText(check);

            }
```

When I run the above, it appears to get all of the strings correctly. When I iterate through the first question, it adds 1 to my score if the answer is correct but for each iteration after it thinks the answer is wrong, even though I know it's right.

I output my answer and the correct answer so I know they match.

Is this a sequence thing?

EDIT

As someone suggested, I was setting the "check" var after my compare. I changed it to the following and it works:

```
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                String check = t3.getText().toString();
                String answer = mEdit.getText().toString();
                questioncount++;


                if (answer.equals(check)) {
                    currentscore++;
                    //t3.setText("CORRECT");

                }
                else {
                    currentscore--;
                    //t3.setText("WRONG");
                };


                t4.setText(answer+" "+currentscore);
                t2.setText("Question "+questioncount+" of 20");

                final double randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(arraycount+1));
                t.setText(gcse_defs[(int) randomnumber]);
                check = gcse_terms[(int) randomnumber];
                t3.setText(check);

            }
```

Comment: Can you be more clear on what your question is?

Comment: its Java not Javascript

Comment: Richard, are you coding in Notepad or something? A professional IDE will flag the `String check = ...` line and tell you that you have declared a local variable which is hiding a global variable. You would immediately notice that you are about to make a blunder.

Comment: Somehow, that looks a lot more like *JavaScript*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void onClick(View view){

    ...
     if (answer.equals(check)) {   // use a class member "check"

    ...
     String check = gcse_terms[(int) randomnumber];   // Declare use and display
     t3.setText(check);                             // local variable
```

Omit the "String" so it's not a declaration!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though you have two variables called "check".